# Prove if we have for all $0 \leq k \leq n, \, \int_0^1 x^k f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x =0$ then $f$ has at least $n+1$ zeroes.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $f\in \mathcal{C}^0([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ such that, $$\forall 0 \leq k \leq n, \,\int_0^1 x^kf(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=0$$ prove that $f$ has at least $n+1$ zeroes.

**What I've done so far:**

I know if $g \in \mathcal{C}^0([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ is non-negative on $[0,1]$ then,

$$\displaystyle \int_0^1g(x)=0 \implies g=0$$

Therefore, if $\displaystyle \int_0^1f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x =0$ then there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c) = 0$ using the contrapositive of the previous result.

Moreover, I am able to show also the result for $n=1$ by using a primitive $F$ of $f$ and Rolle's theorem.

---

I don't know yet how to proceed, any comment/hint/answer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $f$ has at most $n$ zeroes, in particular, it changes sign at most $n$ times. Let $p$ be the polynomial with the sign-changing zeroes as roots. Investigate $\int p(x)f(x)\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Thank you for this hint! This was really helpful.